# In PostgreSQL, How to find which table uses specific Sequence?

Tags: postgresql

I have a sequence called seque_post.

I need to find out in what table it's being used.
Is there a way to write a query that will give the table name?

I wrote this query to find the sequence:

```
select *
from pg_class
where relname like 'seque_post'
```

there is a filed there `reltoastrelid` which according to the [manual](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/8.1/static/catalog-pg-class.html) gives:

> OID of the TOAST table associated with this table, 0 if none. The TOAST table stores large attributes "out of line" in a secondary table.

but i'm not sure how to continue from here.. suggestions?

Comment: This may depend how thorough you want to be - a sequence in Postgres can be "owned by" a single table and column (e.g. when created by the pseudo-type `Serial` or `BigSerial`), but can be the default for any number of other columns, or just used manually in some function somewhere.

Comment: TOAST is to do with storing large values (e.g. long strings in a `text` column) so is not relevant to this question.

Comment: @IMSoP in my sequences are mostly used as `Serial`, so if it's being used somewhere it's surly as PK for column. Since I don't know where it's being used I'll need to look up everywhere... But it's more likely to be used as PK for table... regarding the TOAST, as I said I don't really know how to solve this problem.. it was just a wild guess.

Answer (score 22, accepted):

To find the table a sequence is "related" to, you can use something like this:

```
select seq_ns.nspname as sequence_schema, 
       seq.relname as sequence_name,
       tab_ns.nspname as table_schema,
       tab.relname as related_table
from pg_class seq
  join pg_namespace seq_ns on seq.relnamespace = seq_ns.oid
  JOIN pg_depend d ON d.objid = seq.oid AND d.deptype = 'a' 
  JOIN pg_class tab ON d.objid = seq.oid AND d.refobjid = tab.oid
  JOIN pg_namespace tab_ns on tab.relnamespace = tab_ns.oid
where seq.relkind = 'S' 
  and seq.relname = '[your sequence name]'
  and seq_ns.nspname = 'public';
```

Just to complete the picture:

The other way round (looking up a sequence for a column) is easier, because Postgres has a function to find the sequence for a column:

```
select pg_get_serial_sequence('public.some_table', 'some_column');
```

Comment: I'd just found `pg_depend`, but my query is much uglier than this. I found myself writing `select oid from pg_class where relname='pg_class'`; the `classid` and `refclassid` columns on that table are weird.

Comment: I don't understand the 2nd way... I don't know what is the column name nor the table name.. that is what i'm looking for.

Comment: @John I think "the other way" was meant to mean "looking up in the other direction". It doesn't apply to your case, but might be useful for other readers.

Comment: @John: I just added the second example to complete the picture (and show both ways)

Comment: @IMSoP the other way is very easy.. just go to table create statement and see where the sequence is being used :)

Comment: You can modify the second case for a much simpler solution: `SELECT attrelid::regclass, attname FROM pg_attribute WHERE pg_get_serial_sequence(attrelid::regclass::text, attname) = 'public.seque_post'`

Comment: @NickBarnes That's very nifty. You should post it as a separate answer, because it might inspire people who have similar but not identical problems. :)

Comment: I suggested an edit so that people don't have to read a bunch to figure out that they should replace 'seque_post' with their own sequence name. nbd though. Thanks a ton for this.

Answer (score 3):

The key catalog here is the rather versatile [`pg_depend`](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/interactive/catalog-pg-depend.html), which can connect basically any two items of any sort.

The `::regclass` cast is a magic trick for converting to and from `oid`s, which allows you to look up something like this, with no joins (but possible ambiguities):

```
select 
    D.refobjid::regclass, -- the target table name
    D.* -- see docs for meaning of other columns
from 
    pg_depend as D
where 
    -- source is a relation (in this case, a sequence)
    D.classid = 'pg_catalog.pg_class'::regclass 
    -- target is also a relation (in this case, a table)
    and D.refclassid = 'pg_catalog.pg_class'::regclass
    -- source is the sequence you're looking for, fully qualified name
    and D.objid = 'public.seque_post'::regclass
```

Comment: it gives error `ERROR: schema "filter_rules" does not exist`

Comment: @John That's just the name of the sequence I was testing with. Edited to clarify.

Answer (score 2):

Try this using pg_depend instead of pg_class:

```
SELECT d.refobjid::regclass, a.attname
FROM   pg_depend d
JOIN   pg_attribute a ON a.attrelid = d.refobjid AND a.attnum = d.refobjsubid
WHERE  d.objid = 'public."seque_post"'::regclass;
```

If you add the join to pg_attribute then you even have the column name that uses the sequence.
The ::regclass cast can be used to magically convert object identifiers to relation names.

Hope that helps.